# Share object between two componets in Blazor

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-server-side, razor-components

I'm trying to get an object from one component to another in Blazor. For example, in the first component, I will retrieve data from database and in the second component, I want to display them?

I found solution for sharing value but not the whole object. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: if it's available at startup you could supply it by a service or simply as a service, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection)

Comment: Are the components parent/child or something like that, or are they unrelated (eg siblings in the same page)?